# ScrollPane contentPath in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

In AS2, when we use ScrollPane, there is ***contentPath*** in properties inspector, to assign a movieclip name to scroll it. But how is it in AS3? There is ***source*** instead ***contentPath***. When I insert the movieClip name in ***source*** field doesn't work(error). How I can solve this?

Comment: you've got the answer there - use the source property to set a path to your actionscript exported movieclip.

Comment: My movieclip is in library. In AS2 this is true, but in AS3, when insert the movieclip name in the source field does not work. It shows error

Comment: If you're using the PropertyInspector, pass the AS Linkage name. If you're using actionscript, pass the instance itself, not the name. So if I have a a ScrollPane named `sp` and a MovieClip with an instance name `mc` and linkage name `Mc`, I would set Mc in the Property inspector, or pass mc to sp like so: `sp.source = mc;`...notice there aren't any quotes (`sp.source = 'mc') because I'm passing the actual instance, not it's name. HTH